# Synchronizing two goroutines with a size 1 channel

Tags: go

In an effort to learn golang, I was looking through the go source for reverseproxy:

https://golang.org/src/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go

I found this block of code (truncated):

```golang
...
    errc := make(chan error, 1)
    spc := switchProtocolCopier{user: conn, backend: backConn}
    go spc.copyToBackend(errc)
    go spc.copyFromBackend(errc)
    <-errc
    return
}

// switchProtocolCopier exists so goroutines proxying data back and
// forth have nice names in stacks.
type switchProtocolCopier struct {
    user, backend io.ReadWriter
}


func (c switchProtocolCopier) copyFromBackend(errc chan<- error) {
    _, err := io.Copy(c.user, c.backend)
    errc <- err
}

func (c switchProtocolCopier) copyToBackend(errc chan<- error) {
    _, err := io.Copy(c.backend, c.user)
    errc <- err
}
```

The portion that caught my attention was the creation of the errc buffered channel. I thought (probably naively) that we would use an unbuffered channel and the later receive from errc would need to run twice, like this:

```
<-errc
<-errc
```

As written, I understand that reading from the channel will ensure at least one of the copy methods has run. I also understand that the first send to the channel will not block, while the second will block only if the first one has not yet been received.

What I don't understand, is why it is written like this. Is it to ensure that only one of the methods completes? If that is the case, couldn't they technically both run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The channel of size one helps realize a binary semaphore.

Since at most one value is consumed from the channel (on line 549), changing the size of the channel to be greater than one will not affect the currently exhibited behavior, which is wait until at least one of the two go routines complete executing the `Copy` operation.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Just to clarify, it's also possible that both goroutines complete, correct?

Comment: Since the channel is of size 1, one of the go routines will wait to send on the channel until the current value in the channel is consumed on line 549.  Upon consumption, the waiting go routine will unblock and send on the channel.  The completion of this go routine depends on the scheduler and the completion of the containing program.